# How to showing default empty value in date picker wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my sample, I want to display a default value like '...' in the date picker on WPF.

I used a fallback value, but it will only be shown date time value. But I need an empty value, so how I can achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: '...' is not a DateTime. Are you trying to replace the watermark or what are you trying to do?

Comment: @mm8 yes, i want to change the water mark in datepicker.

Comment: @sameer: So did you try Akhitha M D's suggestion?

Comment: @mm8 yeah, i was tried Akhitha M D's suggesstion, but its changed water mark when loading the datepicker, but i need to change the watermark text at run time.

Comment: @sameer: What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF DatePicker the default text "`Select a date`" is a watermark which is attached as a child control of DatePicker. If you want to display default text like "..." , You have to find the 'PART_Watermark' ContentControl which is the child of DataPicker and change its Content.

You can refer the code by Matt Hamilton in the given reference link:

> http://matthamilton.net/datepicker-watermark

If you want to do it programatically on click of some Button, then check the code below: -

```
    void ChangeDatePickerWaterMark()
    {
        var dp = datePicker as DatePicker; //datePicker is your control name
        if (dp == null) return;

        var tb = GetChildOfType<DatePickerTextBox>(dp);
        if (tb == null) return;

        var wm = tb.Template.FindName("PART_Watermark", tb) as ContentControl;
        if (wm == null) return;

        wm.Content = "...";
    }

    public static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeDatePickerWaterMark();
    }
```

Comment: i tried to your suggesstion but i want to change the watermark text at runtime,

Comment: In the above code they have binded it while loading (loading is happening at run time). I hope you just want to change it programatically on click of some button or something like that right? I have edited the answer, have a look at it.

Comment: Note: It's important that you call `ChangeDatePickerWaterMark()` after rendering. **Don't call it in the constructor**, because this doesn't work. For example you can use the `Loaded` event for calling.

Answer (score 0):

If you just like to remove the watermark text "Select a date", you could use a style and set the Opacity property to zero when Text property is empty.

```html
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```